# AngularJs:$http.get() is not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I use $http.get() to read the json data from the file and we assign the readed data to another scope variable.But the problem is  first it assign the value to the scope variable then its call the success function.

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
    app.controller('MyControl', function ($scope, $http) {

        var $config = {
            url: 'CriticalPath.json',
            method: 'GET',
            async: true,
            transformResponse: function (value) {
                return $.parseJSON(value, true, true);
            }
        }

        $scope.myData = [];
        $http($config).success(
            function (response) {
                $scope.myData = response;
            });

        $scope.Options = {
            DataSource: 'myData',
        };
    });
```

We want to call the success function first

Help me to solve this problem

Comment: This is normal behavior if I understand you correctly. Your JSON needs time to be fetched from the server and during the compile time of your controller there is no data available. That is why `$scope.myData` is an empty array. Take a look: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: gearsdigital is right. What you usually do is show some kind of "loading" message that you remove on the success function.

Comment: @Sindhu, Could you explain why the is a problem for you?

Comment: @gearsdigital,we try to read the data from the json file and assign that data to datasource of our control.but it read data after the compilation of control

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment mentioned, your response data is not available while the controller is parsed by your browser. That is why your $scope object gets not filled with data...

A simple solution could be to move your `DataSource` Object into the success Method. I refactored your code a bit, too.

It's also a good practice not to pollute the global scope. Avoid this issue by wrapping your code in an immediately invoked function expression ([IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)).

This is a working solution (http://jsfiddle.net/afgyvt6j):

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
    app.controller('MyControl', function ($scope, $http) {

        // don't add $ to variables, that is a bad practice
        var config = {
            url: 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos',
            method: 'GET',
            // async: true, not need (default value is true)
            transformResponse: function (value) {
                // when possible, use angular api methods 
                return angular.fromJson(value);
            }
        };

        $http(config).success(function (response) {
            $scope.options = {
                DataSource: response
            };
        });

    });
})();
```

Your template could look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyControl">
    <pre>{{options.DataSource | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is Version with a simple "Loading" animation... http://jsfiddle.net/afgyvt6j/1/